# How to alter the state of a parent based on passed ref in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am attempting to implement an app-wide global header that displays above each route's content.

I envisioned a parent component that controls both the header and a set of children. The header's content is based on which child is currently displayed.

I thought I could accomplish this by sending refs to each child route that would activate when that specific route is rendered. The ref would grab values on the child and set the state of the parent. The header is a child of the parent and takes those values as a prop, thus updating.

Unfortunately, updating the parent component's state when a ref passed to the child is fired causes the ref to be called thousands of times.

```
SceneContainer
  -> Header (Controlled component, changes when scene changes)
  -> Switch (Renders a single route from children, react-router)
     -> Scene -> Route (Has ref, renders when path matches, should change content of header)
     -> Scene -> Route (same as above)
     -> etc
```

[image]

I would like to be able to set a field like this in each "Scene file" that alters the state of the Header. Similar to how React Native handles navigation.

[image]

This is a header that will be across multiple pages, corresponding information to whatever scene it is displaying.[image]

The code for my SceneContainer component is as follows:

```
class SceneContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      title: "from scenecontainer",
      subtitle: "sub from scenecontainer",
    }

    this.generateReference = this.generateReference.bind(this)
  }

  generateReference() {
    return el => {
      console.log("Firing reference")

      if (el !== null) {
        const header = el.wrappedInstance.header
        this.setState(header)
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    let newChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        generateReference: this.generateReference,
      })
    )

    return (
      <div>
        <Header title={this.state.title} subtitle={this.state.subtitle} />
        {newChildren}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SceneContainer
```

"Firing Reference" is shown thousands of times in the console

Comment: I'm not understanding what the point of using `ref` here is. Why not just set state from data like an object?

Comment: @azium I tried to do it like this basically (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) but ended up getting quite a few errors regarding setting state during a transition or something like that. Which is what led me to look to refs. I will see if I can replicate.

Comment: @azium I made an example of my original attempt showing the errors. I think I figured it out with no errors, but could you tell me if this looks correct/idiomatic? https://codesandbox.io/s/gJ39grAmr?module=BA1N